# US 2020 Schedule SE instructions not good

Tags: united-states, income-tax, tax-forms, schedule-se

It seems like the instructions for US 2020 schedule SE are messed up.  There are no instructions that I can find for lines after 4 (and there's even an HTML typo in the online version).  (And most of the information seems to be for church employees.)

Any idea if they are going to fix this?  Thanks.

Comment: Not sure what you're concerned about; [these](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/i1040sse.pdf) seem fine.  Can you clarify what you're seeing?

Comment: As I said: explanations for line 4, then jumps to "Part II".  I posted a separate question about line 8.  I now think part of the issue is that they snuffed the short SE form, so naive folks like me have to use the long one.

Comment: The file I linked had comments for lines later than 4, hence my question.

Comment: @Joe For Part 1, which has 13 lines and is the only part that applies for most people, there are only line-specific instructions for lines 1 and 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the instructions for [Schedule SE](https://www.irs.gov/forms-pubs/about-schedule-se-form-1040) are pretty minimal, and they don’t have details on every line.  They assume that the line descriptions for each line on the schedule itself are self-explanatory. It has been this way for years, so don’t expect an expansion of the instructions anytime soon.

However, we here might be able to help with whatever you are confused about. If you have any specific questions about filling out this schedule, feel free to [ask a new question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Comment: Yes, the instructions are poorly-organized and amazingly confusing. The IRS should have link out to instructions for church employees and farmers, to avoid confusing the 97% of self-employed people who work in other jobs. :)